# Which is pronouncement of Lord mentioned in Vivekachudamani?

Tags: vedanta, identification-request

Vivekachudamani is one of the popular works of Adi Shankaracharya. 233<sup>th</sup> verse of Vivekachudamani is as follows:

> ईश्वरो वस्तुतत्त्वज्ञो न चाहं तेष्ववस्थितः ।
>   न च मत्स्थानि भूतानीत्येवमेव व्यचीक्लृपत् ॥ २३३॥
>
> Īśvaro vastutattvajño na cāhaṃ teṣvavasthitaḥ ।
>   na ca matsthāni bhūtānītyevameva vyacīklṛpat ॥ 233॥
>
> 233. The Lord, who knows the secret of all things has supported this view in the words: "But I am not in them" … "nor are the beings in Me".

This verse says that Ishwar made the procurement or utterance that "But I am not in them" … "nor are the beings in Me". I want to know where Lord said this. Which scripture is this present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Krishna declared that in 9<sup>th</sup> Adhyaya of Bhagavad Gita:

> मया ततमिदं सर्वं जगदव्यक्तमूर्तिना।
>   **मत्स्थानि सर्वभूतानि न चाहं तेष्ववस्थितः**।।9.4।।
>
> 9.4 This whole world is prevaded by Me in My unmanifest form. All beings exist in Me, but I am not contained in them!
>
> **न च मत्स्थानि भूतानि** पश्य मे योगमैश्वरम्।
>   भूतभृन्न च भूतस्थो ममात्मा भूतभावनः।।9.5।।
>
> 9.5 Nor do the beings dwell in Me. Behod My divine Yoga! I am the sustainer and originator of beings, but My Self is not contained in the beings.

See the emphasized words are literally matching with that verse of Vivekachudamani.